# AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: {value} (Program still runs)

Tags: java

So I looked this error up before posting and understand it has something to do with trying to refer to an array value outside of the bounds of an array, but what confuses me is that my class **still runs** as if the error never happened (My guess for this is the differing threads), and that no one thing in my code seems to be causing the error (I followed the stack-trace all the way through); it's just annoying to see the error pop up every so often and I would like to know how to fix it.

My class is a text based grid display that allows for keyboard input (I don't extend the JFrame class because I don't want anyone to be able to resize the display other than by changing the "width" and "height" fields). I hooked it up to another class with a main method that uses the display to play a top-view text-based platformer game to make the error more visible. As I move around, every so often I get an error similar to this one:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.getView(CompositeView.java:160)
    at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getNextVisualPositionFrom(Utilities.java:1030)
    at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.getNextEastWestVisualPositionFrom(CompositeView.java:757)
    at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.getNextVisualPositionFrom(CompositeView.java:479)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.getNextVisualPositionFrom(BasicTextUI.java:1588)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getNextVisualPositionFrom(BasicTextUI.java:1127)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$NextVisualPositionAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:1690)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This is my class:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TextDisplay {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int fontSize;

    private double fontSpacing;

    private char lastChar = 0;
    private int lastKeyPress = 0;
    private int lastKeyRelease = 0;

    private JFrame mainframe;
    private JTextPane field;

    public TextDisplay(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createGUI(false);
        clearDisplay();
    }

    public TextDisplay(int width, int height, boolean visibility) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createGUI(visibility);
        clearDisplay();
    }

    private void createGUI(boolean visibility) {
        mainframe = new JFrame();
        if ((this.width < 1) || (this.height < 1)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        mainframe.setResizable(false);
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        field = new JTextPane();
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                lastChar = e.getKeyChar();
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                lastKeyPress = e.getKeyCode();
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                lastKeyRelease = e.getKeyCode();
            }
        });
        field.setEditable(false);
        setFont(70, 0.0);
        clearDisplay();

        mainframe.add(field);
        if (visibility) {
            mainframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public int getLastKeyPress() {
        return lastKeyPress;
    }

    public int getLastKeyRelease() {
        return lastKeyRelease;
    }

    public char getLastKeyTyped() {
        return lastChar;
    }

    public void clearLastKeyPress() {
        lastKeyPress = 0;
    }

    public void clearLastKeyRelease() {
        lastKeyRelease = 0;
    }

    public void clearLastKeyTyped() {
        lastChar = 0;
    }

    private int calcWindowWidth() {
        FontMetrics fm = field.getFontMetrics(new Font("Consolas", 0, this.fontSize));
        return 12 + fm.charWidth(' ') * this.width;
    }

    private int calcWindowHeight() {
        FontMetrics fm = field.getFontMetrics(new Font("Consolas", 0, this.fontSize));

        double s = this.fontSpacing;
        int fh = fm.getHeight();
        int h = this.height;
        double tf = Math.signum(s) * -4;

        int pixels = 40 + fh * h;
        double spacingPixels = roundB(fh * s * (h - 1));
        int oddPixels = (int) roundB(tf * Math.floor(8 * s / tf) - 8 * s);
        int extraPixels = (int) spacingPixels;
        return pixels + extraPixels - oddPixels;
    }

    public static double roundB(double value) {
        return Math.round(value * 100000000000.0) / 100000000000.0;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        mainframe.setVisible(false);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        mainframe.dispose();
    }

    public boolean isDisplayable() {
        return mainframe.isDisplayable();
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visibility) {
        mainframe.setVisible(visibility);
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        mainframe.setTitle(name);
    }

    public int getFontSize() {
        return this.fontSize;
    }

    public double getFontSpacing() {
        return this.fontSpacing;
    }

    public void setFontSize(int fontSize) {
        setFont(fontSize, this.fontSpacing);
    }

    public void setFontSpacing(double fontSpacing) {
        setFont(this.fontSize, fontSpacing);
    }

    public void setFont(int fontSize, double fontSpacing) {
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
        this.fontSpacing = roundB(fontSpacing);
        mainframe.setSize(calcWindowWidth(), calcWindowHeight());

        StyledDocument doc = field.getStyledDocument();
        MutableAttributeSet mas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(mas, (float) this.fontSpacing);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(mas, this.fontSize);

        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(mas, "Consolas");
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1000, mas, true);
        field.setStyledDocument(doc);
    }

    public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation) {
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(operation);
    }

    public void clearDisplay() {
        StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < this.height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.width; col++) {
                display.append(' ');
            }
            display.append('\n');
        }
        field.setText(display.toString());
    }

    public void setDisplay(char[][] charMap) {
        StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();
        if (charMap.length != this.height) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rows = " + charMap.length + ", this.height = " + this.height);
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < charMap.length; row++) {
            if (charMap[row].length != this.width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "row = " + row + ", length = " + charMap[row].length + ", this.width = " + this.width);
            }
            char[] arrayOfChar;
            int j = (arrayOfChar = charMap[row]).length;
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                char c = arrayOfChar[i];
                display.append(c);
            }
            display.append('\n');
        }
        field.setText(display.toString());
    }

    public void setDisplay(String[] lines) {
        StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();
        if (lines.length != this.height) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rows = " + lines.length + ", this.height = " + this.height);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            String string = lines[i];
            if (string.length() != this.width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "row = " + i + ", length = " + string.length() + ", this.width = " + this.width);
            }
            display.append(string + '\n');
        }
        field.setText(display.toString());
    }

    public String[] getDisplay() {
        return field.getText().split("\n");
    }

    public char[][] getDisplayCharMap() {
        String[] display = getDisplay();
        char[][] charMap = new char[this.height][this.width];
        for (int row = 0; row < this.height; row++) {
            charMap[row] = display[row].toCharArray();
        }
        return charMap;
    }

    public void setCharAt(char character, int row, int col) {
        char[][] display = getDisplayCharMap();
        if ((row >= this.height) || (col >= this.width) || (row < 0) || (col < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("row = " + row + ", this.height = " + this.height + ", col = " + col
                    + ", this.width = " + this.width);
        }
        display[row][col] = character;
        setDisplay(display);
    }

    public char getCharAt(int row, int col) {
        char[][] display = getDisplayCharMap();
        if ((row >= this.height) || (col >= this.width) || (row < 0) || (col < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("row = " + row + ", col = " + col);
        }
        return display[row][col];
    }

    public void output(String text, int row, int col) {
        char[][] display = getDisplayCharMap();
        if ((row >= this.height) || (col >= this.width) || (row < 0) || (col < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("row = " + row + ", col = " + col);
        }
        char[] arrayOfChar = text.toCharArray();
        for (char c : arrayOfChar) {
            display[row][col] = c;

            col++;
            if (col >= this.width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
            if (row >= this.height) {
                row = 0;
            }
        }
        setDisplay(display);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }
}
```

This is the class I used with the main method:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    volatile static int key;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextDisplay display = new TextDisplay(10, 5);
        display.setDisplay(new String[] {"OXXXXXXXXO","X        X","X        X","X        X","OXXXXXXXXO"});
        display.setVisible(true);

        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        boolean gameRunning = true;

        display.setCharAt('P', y, x);

        while (gameRunning) {
            key = display.getLastKeyPress();
            if (key != 0) {
                display.setCharAt(' ', y, x);
                switch (key) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y, x - 1) == ' ') x--;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y - 1, x) == ' ') y--;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y, x + 1) == ' ') x++;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y + 1, x) == ' ') y++;
                    break;
                }
                display.setCharAt('P', y, x);
                display.clearLastKeyPress();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can live with the error, but its quite annoying; could someone help me fix this?
EDIT: Figured this was impractical, so I just extended JFrame and wrapped any time I was changing the display with `invokeLater`. When I did this the error disappeared. Thanks to tsolakp for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing Swing UI state from main thread inside your `while` loop.

Keep in mind that after calling `setVisible` on `display` object the Event Dispatch Thread is started and you cannot modify UI directly after that call.

Swing does not guarantee proper operation in this type of usage.

Try to wrap all calls to `display' variable after`setVisible`call with`invokeLater`.

**1) Here is the code the uses `invokeLater`:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextDisplay display = new TextDisplay(10, 5);
    display.setDisplay(new String[] {"OXXXXXXXXO","X        X","X        X","X        X","OXXXXXXXXO"});
    display.setVisible(true);

    Helper helper = new Helper(display);

    boolean gameRunning = true;

    while (gameRunning) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> helper.check() );           
    }
}

private static class Helper{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    TextDisplay display = null;

    public Helper(TextDisplay display){
        this.display = display;
        display.setCharAt('P', y, x);
    }

    public void check(){
        int key = display.getLastKeyPress();
        if (key != 0) {
            display.setCharAt(' ', y, x);
            switch (key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if (display.getCharAt(y, x - 1) == ' ') x--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if (display.getCharAt(y - 1, x) == ' ') y--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if (display.getCharAt(y, x + 1) == ' ') x++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if (display.getCharAt(y + 1, x) == ' ') y++;
                break;
            }
            display.setCharAt('P', y, x);
            display.clearLastKeyPress();
        }
    }
}
```

**2) You dont really need to `while` loop at all. Just listen to key events.** I just poster the approach with `invokeLater` so that you could familiarize how it can be used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        TextDisplay display = new TextDisplay(10, 5);
        Helper helper = new Helper(display);

        display.setDisplay(new String[] {"OXXXXXXXXO","X        X","X        X","X        X","OXXXXXXXXO"});
        display.addKeyListener(helper);        
        display.setVisible(true);   
    }

    private static class Helper extends KeyAdapter{
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        TextDisplay display = null;

        public Helper(TextDisplay display){
            this.display = display;
            display.setCharAt('P', y, x);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key != 0) {
                display.setCharAt(' ', y, x);
                switch (key) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y, x - 1) == ' ') x--;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y - 1, x) == ' ') y--;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y, x + 1) == ' ') x++;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    if (display.getCharAt(y + 1, x) == ' ') y++;
                    break;
                }
                display.setCharAt('P', y, x);
            }
        }
    }
```

and add this method to your TextDisplay:

```
public void addKeyListener(KeyListener kl){
    field.addKeyListener(kl);
}
```

Comment: I decided to wrap the calls inside the "TextDisplay" class (that way I wouldn't have to worry about wrapping the method outside). After I did this, I found the real error hiding behind everything (using the stack-trace which now works), which was that the "getDisplay()" method was occasionally returning an empty array. How should I go about resolving this? If I wrap the method with invokeLater and use a field variable, I get a NullPointerException. I tried a do-while loop that re-runs until it gives the right sized answer, but eventually that freezes the game entirely.

Comment: I would use SwingTime: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html.

I would also move the whole code that is inside a `while` loop  into a method in `TextDisplay` and would make with `x` and 'y' variables as  instance variables of `TextDisplay`.

Comment: I planned on using `TextDisplay` for multiple purposes, not just as a top-view game; that was just an example to show my error. Also I don't see how a SwingTimer would help. I just wanted to know why .getText() was returning an empty string.

Comment: SwingTimer is preferred way to periodically perform actions to Swing component without worrying about `invokeLater`. Using `while` loop, especially without Thread.sleep is not the right way to work with Swing components.
The alternative is to create another class that will contain `x` and `y` instance variables and the method that wraps while loop body that will be created before the while loop and invoked with `invokeLater`. The idea here is to make sure that `x` and `y` variables are only modified by Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Oh, I forgot we were dealing with multi-threading. I'm probably dealing with values being referenced to without being completely evaluated in the other thread. I'll try a few things and edit my message when I find the answer.

Comment: So I decided to give it up for now. If I need to do something specific I'll just extend JFrame. Anyone who finds an answer can still post though, this is quite the oddity.

Comment: @Zach K. Not sure why you are struggling with this. But I updated the answer with the code I was suggestion you to write. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's alright. I figured my code was impractical anyway, so I just extended JFrame and used invokeLater. The error disappeared when I did this, so it worked out.

Comment: @Zach K. Make sure not to use `while` for listening of key events. Just add another KeyListener to the `field`.